# Telegram getting force closed on VOIP call?

Tags: android, telegram

Getting following error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.SocialMob.Txme, PID: 29963
>                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void
>   org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPController.nativeSetAudioOutputGainControlEnabled(long,
>   boolean) (tried
>   Java_org_telegram_messenger_voip_VoIPController_nativeSetAudioOutputGainControlEnabled
>   and
>   Java_org_telegram_messenger_voip_VoIPController_nativeSetAudioOutputGainControlEnabled__JZ)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPController.nativeSetAudioOutputGainControlEnabled(Native
>   Method)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPController.setAudioOutputGainControlEnabled(VoIPController.java:244)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPBaseService.updateOutputGainControlState(VoIPBaseService.java:691)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPBaseService.configureDeviceForCall(VoIPBaseService.java:445)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPService.startOutgoingCall(VoIPService.java:200)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPService.access$100(VoIPService.java:64)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.voip.VoIPService$1.run(VoIPService.java:127)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Comment: Did you modified Android Telegram to your own application?

Comment: yes, do you have any idea about what is the issue ?

Comment: Use the offiial App from [here](https://telegram.org/dl/android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the libraries of the telegram was updated and was not mentioned on the source code page.

By updating library https://github.com/grishka/libtgvoip, and cleaning my project made my app working fine